# Is my unit test violating "test should do one thing principle"?

Tags: java, unit-testing, tdd

I wrote some unit tests around my class and at the end I am confused whether to combine these tests as their reason of failure will be same.

**PatternBuilder class**

```
public class PatternBuilder {    
    private static final String PATTERN_INITIALS = "#0.%s";

    String buildPatternFromScale(int scale) {
        return String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, PATTERN_INITIALS, StringUtils.repeat("0", scale));
    }
}
```

**Unit tests for the above implementation**

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class PatternBuilderTest {

    private PatternBuilder patternBuilder;

    @Parameterized.Parameter
    public int scale;

    @Parameterized.Parameter(1)
    public String expectedPattern;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        patternBuilder = new PatternBuilder();
    }

    @Parameterized.Parameters(name = "buildPatternFromScale({0}) = {1}")
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
                {1, "#0.0"},
                {2, "#0.00"},
                {5, "#0.00000"},
        });
    }

    @Test
    public void testShouldVerifyThatNonNullPatternIsBuilt() {
        //given

        //when
        String pattern = patternBuilder.buildPatternFromScale(scale);

        //then
        assertThat(pattern, is(notNullValue()));
    }

    @Test
    public void testShouldVerifyThatCorrectPatternOfSpecifiedScaleShouldBeCreated() {

        //when
        String pattern = patternBuilder.buildPatternFromScale(scale);

        //then
        assertThat(pattern, is(equalTo(expectedPattern)));
    }    
}
```

*Will I violate the 'test should do only one thing' if I combine first test with second such that it asserts for no-null-value and correct pattern string ?*

Effectively the one single test will then have following two assertions-

```
assertThat(pattern, is(notNullValue()));
assertThat(pattern, is(equalTo(expectedPattern)));
```

**Reason** - I am thinking to combine them both because if null pattern string is created than it will be fail both tests for one single reason

Comment: Yes, but having a `null` there might cause an exception, which you could also expect/assert.  I don't see anything wrong with having two separate tests though.

Comment: in my opinion you did a very good distinction, just by a glance at the logs u can see where things went wrong

Comment: If it's null it won't be the expected value. I don't find the not-null test to have any value.

Comment: Yes, I was still evaluating. Will do that soon! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your code: you don't need the first test. The second test makes sure that your builder returns an object that is **equal** to an expected pattern.

This test will obviously *fail* if the builder returns a null object!

In that sense: having two different tests doesn't add much value anyway!

In other words: you might *start* with both test, or more precisely: when you follow TDD; you would probably start with that first test case. Later on, when you have implemented your real builder, and the "real" test case is in place - then you don't need that first check-for-null test case any more.

Keep in mind: any line of source code *also* resembles **cost** for you. As long as it is around, it might be read and is required to be understand  (to fix bugs or add functionality). Therefore even unit tests should provide "return on investment" to you. Meaning: tests that don't add significant value to your test bucket are subject to deletion.

Edit, based on the changes to the question. The additional test case

```
@Test
public void testShouldVerifyThatNonNullPatternIsBuilt() {
    //given
    int scale = 1;
```

is still redundant. And "worse" - keep in mind that @Parameterized tests work somehow *different* than "normal JUnit" tests. You see, with the @Parameterized runner in place, **each** test is invoked for **each** data value. Meaning: the above test is called **three** times. The idea is that **all** tests use the data elements. In that sense: it doesn't make sense to have a test in there that does **not** use the "data values". Especially given the fact that this test here tests something that the **other** test checks already.

In other words: `assertThat(pattern, is(equalTo(expectedPattern)))` **will** fail when pattern is null (unless you happen to put **null** into your *expectedPattern*).

Comment: Yes, I agree to the fact here that null object will anyways fail the test or surely break it. But, If i go by one assertion rule and check only pattern considering that null object will break the test, is it good? Should test fail or break?

Comment: No no :) actually I asked you above question

Comment: Aha! thats bad on my part. I actually fixed that issue in my code locally but forgot to add there. I will fix it in question as well.

Comment: @Vishal See my last update then. And consider cleaning up and deleting no longer needed comments.

Answer (score 2):

> Will I violate the 'test should do only one thing' if I combine first
>   test with second such that it asserts for no-null-value and correct
>   pattern string ?

In this case I don't think.
Why ?
Because the first test method :

```
assertThat(pattern, is(notNullValue()));
```

doesn't valid any expected behavior of the `buildPatternFromScale()` method.

This method is designed to return a `Pattern` according what it received as parameter.
The single thing to check is that.
By writing a test method to do a not null assertion, you don't cover the specification of the method. You write just a first step to validate it.

If your method could return `null` in some cases and not `null` in others, it could make sense.
But it is not the case.

So I would replace :

```
assertThat(pattern, is(notNullValue()));
assertThat(pattern, is(equalTo(expectedPattern)));
```

by just :

```
assertThat(pattern, is(equalTo(expectedPattern)));
```

Answer (score 0):

One purpose of "One assertion per test method" rule is that only name of the test method will provide you enough information to understand reason why test failed.

Where if you have multiple assertions in test - you need to read failed message to understand why test failed.

Also with multiple assertions, if first assertion fail other will not be executed.
So for getting "full picture" of possible reason you need re-run tests after fixing first assertion

In your particular case assertion for non-null is same as assertion for equality to expected result. Null result will fail always if expected not null.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd stick with two separate tests.here. If this was done using TDD, you would most likely end up with two tests anyway.

Although its worth mentioning that a test can have a single concept (rather than a thing), which can mean multiple asserts in a single test case, if all related logically.

As mentioned before they key thing you are looking forward is clarity in the test to quickly identify what fails and why, you way you have it gives you this which is important in terms of the value added from having the test .